# postfix multiple receivers delay

Tags: postfix

i have problem, when someone with @domain1 or @domain2 send email tu miltiple receivers, they receive that mail all in different times. I checked maillog and i saw that oder of which user gets mail right away and which 1 hour later is random.

Example log for the first user who received mail:

```
Nov 27 12:13:26 mail postfix/qmgr[4129]: 5E47E43920E2: from=<user1@domain>, size=6344, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 27 12:13:26 mail spamd[7673]: spamd: connection from localhost [::1]:59406 to port 783, fd 6
Nov 27 12:13:26 mail spamd[7673]: spamd: setuid to spamd succeeded
Nov 27 12:13:26 mail spamd[7673]: spamd: processing message <D02A66CA-C108-436E-83BA-F64rfrw@domain> for spamd:1000
Nov 27 12:13:26 mail postfix/smtpd[7592]: disconnect from mail.google.com[1.1.1.1]
Nov 27 12:13:27 mail spamd[7673]: spamd: clean message (-1.9/2.9) for spamd:1000 in 1.0 seconds, 6261 bytes.
Nov 27 12:13:27 mail spamd[7673]: spamd: result: . -1 - BAYES_00,DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,HTML_MESSAGE,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2,SPF_HELO_NONE,SPF_NONE,URIBL_BLOCKED scantime=1.0,size=6261,user=spamd,uid=1000,required_score=2.9,rhost=localhost,raddr=::1,rport=59406,mid=<D02A66CA-C108-436E-83BA-F64ArffA3A7@domain>,bayes=0.000000,autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no
Nov 27 12:13:27 mail postfix/pickup[27709]: 6BE4543920E7: uid=1000 from=<user@domain>
Nov 27 12:13:27 mail postfix/cleanup[7657]: 6BE4543920E7: message-id=<D02A66CA-C108-436E-83BA-F64DEFDSA3A7@domain>
Nov 27 12:13:27 mail postfix/pipe[7647]: 5E47E43920E2: to=<rok.kotnik@mydomaini>, relay=spamassassin, delay=1.2, delays=0.17/0/0/0.98, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
Nov 27 12:13:27 mail postfix/qmgr[4129]: 5E47E43920E2: removed
Nov 27 12:13:27 mail postfix/qmgr[4129]: 6BE4543920E7: from=<user@domain>, size=6775, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 27 12:13:27 mail dovecot: lmtp(7672): Connect from local
Nov 27 12:13:27 mail dovecot: lmtp(rok.kotnik@mydomain): 6IHGGlffwF/4HQfelzaOg: sieve: msgid=<D02A66CA-C108-436E-83BA-Fffffe@domain>: stored mail into mailbox 'INBOX'
Nov 27 12:13:27 mail dovecot: lmtp(7672): Disconnect from local: Successful quit
```

So after around 1 hours the second user will also receive same mail.

Since we only have like 20 users i never before noticed that problem, but it is very anoying.

Anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: These log entries do not show a problem.

Comment: Yes i know, but i didnt knew what else to post. After quite a log of testing i just noticed, that alias mail addresses get email right away, as for the original account (firstname.lastname) took longer. We are using postfix + postfixadmin. Do you have any ideas what should i check ?

Comment: How about log entries that show the problem?

Comment: Log doesnt show any problems. For example i noticed that if user, which have office365 mail server sends email to my postfix, to two recipients: one email account, and other CC to the alias account address, that alias account will receive mail right away, but other account will get mail minutes (or hour) later. (both recipients are under same domain in my mail server )When i check logs i will see first smtp connection right away, and other  minutes later. They will be separated.

Comment: If that is the case, then the problem is with the sending mail server, not yours.

Comment: The time of the second received mail is the same as for the fist one, even if will come 1 hour late. Does this change things ?

Comment: Not in the slightest.